# Subtracting two timestamps columns in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

For my data on S3, I have defined a table in AWS Glue Data Catalog. This table contains two columns of `Timestamp` type. I want to subtract these two columns and show it as different column. I have tried the following query

```sql
SELECT  outtime, intime, outtime-intime AS length
FROM database.table
LIMIT 10
```

However, it gives me the following error.

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:66: '-' cannot be applied to timestamp, timestamp

How can I solve this problem?  I am using Athena to query data in my S3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `date_diff()`, such as:

```
date_diff(second, intime, outtime)
```

This returns the result in seconds.